# iMacro connect to results via sumbitform button if search box is empty

Tags: javascript, form-submit, imacros

I have problem setting up my iMacros that need to collect data for multiple people but I don't know how to get a javasrcipt submitform to work.

The page in question is [THIS ONE](http://www.izs.si/imeniki-seznami/imenik-pooblascenih-inzenirjev/vpogled-v-imenik-pooblascenih-inzenirjev/).

Here I need to tick a checkbox MSGeo then click the sumbitform blue arrow button at the bottom without any other info. Then a few pages of people appear and I copy some TD data from each one. I know how to work that TD stuff. Just the repetetive from going from a user back to the list of users is giving me the problems since BACK command gives me the whole list without the tick at the beginning.

I'm using FF plugin to do this.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With trial and error I figured it on my own:

```
URL GOTO=your_url
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:form_name ATTR=NAME:attribiute_name CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:"javascript:  submitform()"
```

The last line was giving me soem trouble but I finally managed it. :)

Regards,
Aghi